# Oracle Sql - retrieve distinct data from a listagg

Tags: sql, oracle11g

With this command I'm able to retrieve a count of all the distinct `manager_id` grouped by `department_id`

```
select department_id, count( distinct manager_id) 
from employees
group by department_id
```

If I want to see a list of those managers, I can use this but the problem is that they are repeated and not distinct

```
select 
    department_id,
    listagg(manager_id, ' | ') within group(order by manager_id)
from  
    employees
group by 
    department_id;
```

This outputs a long list of repeated `manager_id`.

One row example:

```
100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 121 | 122 | 122 | 122 | 122 | 122 | 122 | 122 | 122 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 123 | 124 | 124 | 124 | 124 | 124 | 124 | 124 | 124
```

I want to be able to have a list of unique manager_ids, not repeating like the above one. How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to remove duplicates:

```
select department_id, count(*),
       listagg(manager_id, ' | ') within group (order by manager_id)
from (select distinct department_id, manager_id
      from employees
     ) e
group by department_id
```